# Connect direct to web service with RhoMobile 4.0

Tags: rhomobile

I am working on application using RhoMobile 4.0. I want to know, how to connect to web service in rhomobile 4.0 without rhoconnect. Need to do http post and get.

Answer (score 0):

Using RhoMobile, you can using the usual AJAX methods to reach a webservice to get or post data.

Additionally you can use the [RhoMobile Network API](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/4.0.0/api/Network) from Ruby or from JavaScript to call a webservice, registering a callback.

For example in Ruby you can have this code in a controller:

```
def getData
  #Perform an HTTP GET request.
  getProps = Hash.new
  getProps['url'] = "http://<my_url>/Json/Server/GetDada?username=admin&password=pass"
  getProps['headers'] = {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}
  Rho::Network.get(getProps, url_for(:action => :get_callback))
  render :action => :transferring
end

def get_callback
  if @params['status'] == "ok"
    get_result = Rho::JSON.parse(@params['body'])

    puts "**** Parsed it" #{@params['body']}"
    # Do something with the data
  end
end
```